# Opening another window through bash script, while keeping the main thread running

Tags: python, linux, bash

What I want to do, is to make a bash script, which at one point starts another terminal with a command in it, and at the same time, keeps the normal program flow in the main thread.

I could do the first part by using

```
xterm -e python something.py
```

But the main program flow also pauses, until the newly opened window is closed.

For suppose,

```
xterm -e python something.py
echo "Wait for sometime"
sleep 7

kill something.py
```

So, here i want to kill the something.py opened in a new window, automatically after 7 seconds. Any way, that could be implemented in bash. Or in Python program itself, to close itself after 7 seconds.

Comment: By the way, these are not threads, they are processes.  Bash does not support multi-threading (yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your line with this:

```
xterm -e python something.py &
```

Note the `&` -- it asks the shell to execute the command in background and resume execution of the script.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew it would be this simple. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Do as @sarnold suggests and use:

```
kill %1
```

To kill the job.

Comment: Ah, once again I was happy to answer part one and missed part two. When the day wraps around and I get more votes I'll be back. :)